# Can I restric user access to the default browser in Android?

Tags: android, settings

I am planning to develop an app that will help the users to protect their Android phones from unauthorized usage. So the user can set to restrict others from using the browser, make calls to a set of numbers, send  sms/mms etc...is it possible to all these...i have seen blogs saying that it is possible and not possible. I am confused..
Please guide me..

http://blog.wangling.me/2009/08/why-it-is-impossible-to-intercept-incoming-calls-on-android/

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

"Can I restric user access to the default browser in Android?" Well,if you really want to restrict user to use the default browser then answer is yes.You can do that.To do that your application will have to run a service that will check running processes periodically.Then from the process name you can find out the package name.For default browser it is com.browser or may be android.com.browser.And you can kill any process by using killBackgroundProcess(pkgName).Check whether browser is in foreground.If it is then send it to the background and apply the method.This you can do in extreme case if you want.But it is really not a good idea and not recommended at all.